# Using API response in different functions without having to call API again

Tags: python, api, python-requests

I am working with an API and parsing different informations on its response, and calling the parsed information in different functions / files.
The issue is that it will call quickInfo() multiple times as a result, creating multiple API requests, which is unwanted as there is a rate limit or cause performance issues (API response is very large).
I am trying to find a way to get the API once and then be able to use the content of the response in different situations.
I could make "reponse" a global variable but I read that it was bad programming and could cause memory leaks.

Simplified code is as follows:

**FILE 1**

```
def quickInfo(name):
       response = requests.get('[website]/product/{}?token=No'.format(name), headers=headers, verify=False).json()
    return response

def parsing(name):
    r = quickInfo(name)
    
    name = "{}".format(r["product"]["name"])
    buyprice_raw = [i["buyprice"] for i in r["avgHistory"]]
    buy_orders = "{:,}".format(r["product"]["buyorders"])
    sell_orders  = "{:,}".format(r["product"]["sellorders"])

    return name, buyprice_raw, buy_orders, sell_orders

def charting(name):
    buyprice, sellprice = parsing(name)
    #code continues
```

**FILE 2**

```
 name, price = parsing(name)
 print(name +"'s price is of " + price) #sample use
 #code continues
```

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The absolute easiest way would be to decorate `quickInfo` with the [`@functools.lru_cache()`](https://docs.python.org/3.9/library/functools.html#functools.lru_cache) decorator, but you'll just have to be aware that it will only ever do a real request once per `name` (unless you clear the cache):

```
import functools

@functools.lru_cache()
def quickInfo(name):
    response = requests.get(
        "[website]/product/{}?token=No".format(name),
        headers=headers,
        verify=False,
    )
    response.raise_for_status()
    return response.json()
```